# Analysis of the ideals of $C[0,1]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, metric-spaces, continuity, ideals

For every ideal $I$ of $C[0,1]$ , define

$Z(I):=\{x \in [0,1] :f(x)=0 , \forall f \in I\}$ and for every $A \subseteq [0,1]$ , let

$I(A):=\{f \in C[0,1] : f(x)=0 , \forall x \in A\}$ . Then clearly $I(A)$ is always an ideal . Let $C[0,1]$ be equipped with the sup metric and $[0,1]$ be equipped with the usual euclidean metric .    I am trying to show the following , please help .

(i) $I(A)$ is closed in $C[0,1]$ for every $A \subseteq [0,1]$

(ii) $Z(I)=Z(\bar I)$

(iii) $I(Z(I))=\bar I$

where $\bar I$ denotes the closure i.e. the set of all adherent points of $I$ . Can someone please provide some link for some material where I can get these things . Thanks in advance

Comment: You can look at the book *Rings of Continuous Functions* by Gillman & Jerison, though I'm not very sure whether you will find any solution there or not.

Comment: I agree with @Krish Another book is by Russell C. Walker, The Stone-Cech Compactification (several of the chapters). The questions you list are not overly difficult, you ought to be able to do them if you understand the definitions and what they are asking, so it might be that many topology or analysis books will do.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(i)  If $\forall x\in A: f_n(x)=0$, what happens with $f=\lim f_n$?

(ii) The nontrivial inclusion is $Z(I)\subset Z(\bar I)$. Read again (i).

(iii) Any $f\in\bar I$ is an uniform limit of $f_n\in I$.